# C - Change focus to new GtkWidget

Tags: user-interface, widget, gtk, focus

I'm working on a gtk UI for an IRC client.
I'd like to add the following interaction to it:

1. On user input: /join #channel
2. Create a new tab < -- Working
3. Set focus on it < -- Not working

I Can't seem to set the focus (not the input focus, the view focus like sttign the widget to be the active view) on the created GtkWidget* on my notebook.
I tried using the grab_focus() function but the focus is still on the is created tab.

What am I missing?

Comment: Post some code (where "some" refers to a minimal compilable example that reproduces your issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget has to be focusable (`gtk_widget_can_focus`), otherwise `gtk_widget_grab_focus` will not do anything.

---

Also there is no such thing as "view-focus". You have the input focus and the window focus.

- window focus - makes your application receive mouse/keyboard events.
- widget input focus - makes your widget receive keyboard events if the window is focussed

Note that `input` here means input event (a `GtkButton` usually only handles the <kbd>Enter</kbd> whereas a `GtkScale` handles <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and may handle the <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well).

Comment: I managed to do it using `gtk_wifget_can_focus` with `gtk_widget_grab_focus`! Thanks for the explanations btw!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer (tick next to it) instead of editing the title (as soon as you tick it, it will be listed as solved).